# Fibonacci-Python

Tags: python

Construa uma função, ou seja, um algoritmo que
receba o número máximo da sequência de
Fibonacci.

Retornando todos os números a partir de zero até
o numero de Fibonacci menor ou igual ao número
informado.
Exemplo:

Função – `fibonacci(10)`

Retornará – `0,1,1,2,3,5,8`

```
print (" Trabalho de Fibonacci ")

n =int( input(" Digite Quantos termos você deseja :"))
t1 = 0
t2 = 1

print("{} . {} .".format(t1,t2), end="")

cont = 6

while cont <= n:
    t3 = t1 + t2
    print ("  {}.".format(t3),end="")
    t1 = t2
    t2 = t3
    cont +=1

print( " Fim ")
```

O código dá um erro, já tentei alterar o `cont` para 3 mas não funcionou.

Comment: Se você quer calcular o número de Fibonacci menor ou igual ao número informado, o que este `cont` está fazendo? Será que ele é mesmo necessário?

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de utilizar a variável `cont` para definir a quantidade de repetições, utilize a própria variável `t3`, já que ela será a responsável por receber os números da sequência de Fibonacci. Dessa forma:

```
print (" Trabalho de Fibonacci ")

n =int( input(" Digite Quantos termos você deseja :"))
t1 = 0
t2 = 1
t3 = 0

while t3 <= n:
    print("{}.".format(t3), end="")
    t3 = t1 + t2
    t1 = t2
    t2 = t3

print( " Fim ")
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input('A sequência de Fibonacci de: '))
a, b = 0, 1
while a < n:
    print(a, end=',')
    a, b = b, a+b
print('FIM')
```

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que dessa forma possa te ajuda:

```
n =int( input(" Digite um teto para a sequência de Fibonacci :"))
t1 = 1
t2 = 0
t3 = 0
t4 = []

while t1 <= n:
    t4.append(t1)
    t3 = t1 + t2
    t2 = t1
    t1 = t3

print(t4)
```

Answer (score -1):

Meu código realmente funciona.

```
num = int(input())
def fibonacci(n):
    t1 = 0
    t2 = 1
    t3 = 0
    for _ in range(0, n):
        print(t1)
        t3 = t1 + t2
        t1 = t2
        t2 = t3
fibonacci(num)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lista = ['1', '1']
for contador in range(2,int(input('Digite a quantidade de elementos da série fibonacci que deseja exibir:'))):
    lista.append(int(lista[len(lista) - 2]) + int(lista[len(lista) - 1]))
print(lista)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
x = input(int("Digite um inteiro positivo"))
a = 1; b = i = 0
print(f"Estes são os primeiros {x} termos da série de Fibonacci:")
print('\u26C4'*10)
while i < x:
    c = a + b
    a = b
    b = c
    i += 1
    print(a)
phi = a
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo Hick. Duas coisas: 1) leia o help (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) sempre que tiver duvidas antes de postar qualquer coisa, e se notar no topo do editor do site tem um sinal de interrogação (lado direito) que mostra que se clicar explica muito bem como formatar 2) o ideal das respostas aqui não é só dar um exemplo pronto que funciona, é explicar o processo. Eu não testei seu código, mas olhando por cima parece que tem coisa a mais que é um print com um valor que provavelmente é para colorir o terminal e no loop a variavel `c` já resolveria quando encerrar (não olhei direito)

Comment: Obrigado. Tem um caractere unicode de um boneco de neve que não é necessário para o código. Coloquei em vez de print('-'*10).